# How can I "add_dependencies(..)" to an "UNKNOWN IMPORTED" library?

Tags: cmake

I want to use [this way](https://gist.github.com/johnb003/65982fdc7a1274fdb023b0c68664ebe4#file-external_gtest-cmake) of getting `googletest` in my project. But there seems to be something wrong:

```
ninja: error: 'libsuper/test/googletest-prefix/src/googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.a', needed by 'libdsuper/test/libsuper_test', missing and no known rule to make it
```

As I understand the error, there is no gtest library available when ninja tries to build the test-executable. As a consequence, I added a dependency just after the test-target:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_test ${SOURCES})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_test ${GTEST_LIBRARY})
```

But this has no effect. It seams like it's silently ignored. I guess this is because `IMPORTED` is meant for system libraries that need not to be compiled and are thus available from the start. In my case, this is however not true. The `googletest` libraries are only available after they have been compiled by the `ExternalProject_Add`.

Is this also linked to `ninja`? The site linked above does not mention problems - and I could imagine that's because `googletest` and `libSomeOtherThingThatUsesGTest` are build in sequence, as `make` does.

How can I instruct cmake to wait until the `gtest` library is truly available?

Comment: Did you try to locate where the supposed "libgtest.a" is build ?
Maybe the https://gist.github.com/johnb003/65982fdc7a1274fdb023b0c68664ebe4#file-external_gtest-cmake-L24 is wrong on this platform

Comment: Hmm, I thought that whether ExternalProject has actually been built or not should be clearly followed from the build log.

Comment: @dani: On Stack Overflow we want to have a code in the question post itself, not linked. If the linked gist will become unavailable since some time (or its content will be changed), your question will become *useless*. Actually, the gist content is not so long, and you may add it to the question post entirely. Please, do that. (And, after copiing the code into the question post, make sure that exactly this code you have tried).

Answer (score 2):

There is a little sense to be depended on *IMPORTED* library target - there is **no actions** bonded with such target, so you are actually depends on nothing.

Instead, you should depend on a **target, which creates the library**. In case of External Project, this is a target created for such project (the first argument to the `ExternalProject_Add` function's call).

---

In case of normal (non-*IMPORTED*) library target situation is quite different: actions for create such library are bonded with the target itself, so being dependent from the library target means that library should be built before the dependee. But such dependence is rarely used: instead, one *links* with the library *target*, which by itself implies the dependency from the actions, bonded with that target.

Comment: No agree with "There is a little sense to be depended on IMPORTED library target", here `gtest` imported target depend on `googletest` ExternalProject command. And this imported target define some interface properties to "target_link with".
Also cf: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries
`IMPORTED libraries are useful for convenient reference from commands like target_link_libraries()`

Comment: OK, thanks for info. Dependency between targets `gtest` and `googletest` is what I didn't take into account. But this dependency should be **explicitely** noted in the question post (link to gist in insufficient according to Stack Overflow rules). After the question post will be fixed, I will probably remove my answer.

Comment: no problem, I guess like you, we don't want to see SO with wrong statement ;). BTW we still don't know why it didn't work although I have  strong suspicion on imported location path...
EDIT: maybe googletest built only in `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON` by default ?

Comment: see my comment below Mizux Dev's answer. Could it be possible that add_dependency is ignored for IMPORTED targets? Could it be that the error occours because ninja want's to build things in parallel (compared to make)?

Comment: `Could it be possible that add_dependency is ignored for IMPORTED targets?` - While docs for [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html) doesn't clearly define dependency from *IMPORTED* target, docs for [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_dependencies.html) are very clear about this case. `Could it be that the error occours because ninja want's to build things in parallel (compared to make)?` - I don't know, but make also is able to build in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

for googletest you should use:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_test ${SOURCES})
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_test gtest)
```

Dependency will be automatically managed.
Also the imported target gtest already depends on googletest ExternalProject_Add according to [this](https://gist.github.com/johnb003/65982fdc7a1274fdb023b0c68664ebe4#file-external_gtest-cmake-L31)

I guess the errors come from the fact that the path for the imported target file location aka `${binary_dir}/googlemock/gtest/${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}gtest.a` is wrong IMHO.

Comment: The path is not wrong. In fact, the error occours before anything is starting to build. there can't be any gtest.a since the dependency is ignored.